# Windows Socket TCP Client Receives data only every 200ms (QTCPSocket)

Tags: windows, macos, qt, sockets, tcp

I am using `QTCPSocket` to connect to a TCP server (which is running on Ubuntu). The server is sending at minimum, a 1 byte packet every 40ms. My application is real-time, so it is important I receive data as fast as possible at the cost of extra network traffic.

Once I have connected a TCP Client from Windows, I start receiving packets. However, the `readyRead()` signal from the `QTCPSocket` is only emitted once every 200ms (with 5 bytes in the packet). I have looked at the packets in Wireshark, they are actually 5 byte packets coming across.

However, using `QTCPSocket` on Mac (the exact same code in fact), I get individual packets every time, all of my 1 byte packets sent arrive as single byte packets, which is great.

I tried creating a raw Windows socket (not using `QTCPSocket`), and get identical behaviour to `QTCPSocket` on Windows.

What is the difference causing the Mac socket to receive packets at a much higher time resolution? Is there something I can set in `setsockopt()` which will prevent this 200ms buffering from occuring?

I am aware that setting `TCP_NODELAY` on the server side will probably solve my problem, but seeing as the Mac  TCP Client works as intended, there must be a way to get the same behaviour on Windows.

Comment: Setting `mySocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);` on the server side is the only way I have found to remedy this problem

Comment: You tried fixing the protocol first? Because that's always worked for me.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. UDP might be better for that kind of usage.

Comment: @Roku: Not likely as he'd have to handle retransmissions, duplicates, transmit pacing, and the like all by himself. UDP is a better choice if TCP does something expensive that you don't need. But if your thinking is "I can do everything TCP does but better somehow", forget it.

Comment: It depends on the environment and reliability requirements. If the environment is a local area network with low load, and if it is not fatal for the application to miss one packet once in a month, then UDP is realiable enough. Of course it is not wise to try to build your own TCP on top of UDP. You just need to known how those protocols work, your own requirements and choose accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting mySocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1); on the server side is the only way I have found to remedy this problem

Answer (score 0):

For others who stumble upon this coming from search engines:

The above (correct) answer by [oggmonster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590032/oggmonster) can also be described by:

```
int on = 1;
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&on, sizeof(on)))
  {
  return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to acknowledge each byte of data you receive to give the reply ACKs some data to piggyback on. Talk to whoever designed your protocol.

Trying to answer questions like "Why does it work on X and not on Y" is only useful when both behaviors aren't correct. If it has no application-level acknowledgements, then both behaviors are correct. If one of them shouldn't be correct, then the protocol should have a mechanism to control that, such as application-layer acknowledgements. If it doesn't the protocol is broken. Trying to figure out why a broken protocol doesn't work is pointless -- it doesn't work because it's broken.